# Best way to find indexes of first occurences of integers in each row of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array such as:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4],
              [8, 7, 7, 7, 4, 8, 8]])
```

what would be the best way to get as output:

```
array([[0, 2, 5, 6], [0, 1, 4]])
```

or

```
array([[0, 2, 5, 6], [4, 1, 0]])
```

These are the indices of the first occurence of each integer in each row. The order of the indices is not important.

Currently I am using:

```
res = []
for row in a:
  unique, unique_indexes = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
  res.append(unique_indexes)
```

But I wonder if there is a (num)pythonic way to avoid the for loop.

Comment: Since what you have is not an actual array (ragged arrays are better represented as lists), the loop is fairly optimal.

Comment: if by ragged you mean that the rows have different lengths, actually here the initial array a is not ragged I think

Comment: The initial array yes, but the result is necessarily ragged, at least in the general case. And as I say that, I found a better solution. Give me a minute to write it up.

Comment: thank you ! yes for the result you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the array in such a way that you process the entire thing in one batch. Let's start with an example very similar to the one in your question:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4], [8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 8, 8]])
```

Now get the indices:

```
_, ix = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
# ix = array([ 0,  2,  5,  6, 11,  8,  7])
```

Notice that the indices of the first elements are correct. The following elements are offset by the size of `a`. In general, the offset is

```
offset = ix // a.shape[-1]
# offset = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
ix %= a.shape[-1]
# ix = array([0, 2, 5, 6, 4, 1, 0])
```

You can call `np.split` on the new `ix` at every location where `offset` changes value:

```
ix = np.split(ix, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(offset)) + 1)
```

So why is this example valid, but the one in the question is not? The key is that  `np.unique` uses a sort-based approach (which makes it run in `O(n log n)` rather than the `O(n)` of `collections.Counter`). That means that for the order of the indices to be correct, each row must be unique from and larger than the previous row. Notice that in your example, `4` appears in both rows. You can ensure this with a simple check of the  `max` and `min` values in each row:

```
mn = a.min(axis=1)
mx = a.max(axis=1)
diff = np.r_[0, (mx - mn + 1)[:-1].cumsum(0)] - mn
# diff = array([-4, -4])
b = a + diff[:, None]
# b = array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3],
             [7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7]])
```

Notice that you have to offset the cumulative sum by one to get the right index. If you deal with large integers and/or very large arrays, you will have to be more careful about making `diff` to avoid overflow.

Now you can use `b` in place of `a` in the call to `np.unique`.

**TL;DR**

Here is a general no-loop approach, applicable to any axis, not just the last:

```
def global_unq(a, axis=-1):
    n = a.shape[axis]
    a = np.moveaxis(np.asanyarray(a), axis, -1).reshape(-1, n)
    mn = a.min(-1)
    mx = a.max(-1)
    diff = np.r_[0, (mx - mn + 1)[:-1].cumsum(0)] - mn
    _, ix = np.unique(a + diff[:, None], return_index=True)
    return np.split(ix % n, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ix // n)) + 1)
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly, interesting approach !
 I do not know numpy well enough to know if there is an improvement in complexity in the end, in comparison with the for loop, but any case it is nice.

Comment: @aurelien_morel. There isn't. You incur a penalty for sorting larger arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could put it into a list comprehension, but your loop is fairly clean already:

```
[list(np.unique(e, return_index=True)[-1]) for e in a]
# [[0, 2, 5, 6], [4, 1, 0]]
```